# Turning ruby string into datetime

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

Is it possible to turn 7/1/13 16:37 into a proper ruby DateTime object? Time.new and Time.parse seem to return the wrong thing...

```
 Time.parse("7/1/13 16:37")
  => 2007-01-13 16:37:00 -0500
```

Comment: proper means what? what is missing in your one,you are thinking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **strptime** function, check [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#M000214) out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`DateTime.parse(...)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'time'
x = DateTime.parse("7/1/13 16:37")
x.class # => DateTime
```